# How to import txt file with different amount of delimiters in columns in R

Tags: r, csv, data.table

I am importing a txt file in R, with semicolon ";" delimiters.

There are 28 columns in the file that has almost 8 million observations. However, in some lines, the delimiters are poorly formatted, so in some cases, there are 26 or 27 delimiters instead of 28. This causes R to stop importing when it encounters one of these poorly formatted lines. I could adjust the raw file, but there are thousands of observations, making the process very tedious.

I am using `fread` from `data.table`. Is there any way to solve this? Maybe import only the lines with the correct number of delimiters (how could I do that)?

Thank you for any help!

Something like that:

```
col1;col2;col3;col4;col5;col6;col7;col8;col9;col10;col11;col12;col13;col14;col15;col16;col17;col18;col19;col20;col21;col22;col23;col24;col25;col26;col27;col28
1;2;3;4;5;6;7;8;9;10;11;12;13;14;15;16;17;18;19;2;0;21;22;23;24;25;26;27;
1;2;3;4;5;6;7;8;9;10;11;12;13;14;15;16;1;7;18;19;20;21;22;23;24;25;26;27;
This is a line of text;2;3;4;5;6;7;8;9;10;11;12;13;14;15;16;17;18;19;20;21;22;23;24;25;26;27;
1;2;3;4;5;6;7;8;9;10;11;12;13;14;15;16;17;18;19;20;21;22;23;24;25;26;
1;2;3;4;5;6;7;8;9;10;11;12;13;14;15;16;17;18;19;20;21;22;23;24;25;26;27;
This is a;nother line of text;2;3;4;5;6;7;8;9;10;11;12;13;14;15;16;17;18;19;20;21;22;23;24;25;26;27;
1;2;3;4;5;6;7;8;9;10;11;12;13;14;15;16;17;18;19;20;21;22;23;24;25;26;27;;
```

Comment: Can you provide your (shortened) CSV file for us?

Comment: `fill = TRUE` might be what you need, e.g. `data.table::fread("file.txt", fill = TRUE)` and then look for `NA` or filter with `complete.cases`

Comment: I put an example @dufei

Comment: How do I look for `NA` or filter with `complete.cases`, in that case? @André Wildberg

Comment: In this example all values of the last column `col28` are `NA`. Is that wanted?

Comment: Yes @Andre Wildberg !

Comment: Well, then `complete.cases` would filter all of them out because they're not complete ;)

Comment: If you have delimiters missing, like you said, using `fill=TRUE` will put `NA` and keep on reading the file. Finding missing delimiters within lines is not possible in an easy way because there is no assignment of values to a specific column. Maybe doable by checking the class of values but still error prone.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suggest you read in each line as a single character string and then use `separate_wider_delim()` to split each line at the semicolon. This function can handle different row lengths by specifying the `too_few` argument:

```r
library(tidyverse)

test <- read_lines("test.csv")

tibble(col = test[-1]) |> 
  separate_wider_delim(
    col, 
    delim = ";", 
    names_sep = "_",
    too_few = "align_start")
#> # A tibble: 7 × 29
#>   col_1     col_2 col_3 col_4 col_5 col_6 col_7 col_8 col_9 col_10 col_11 col_12
#>   <chr>     <chr> <chr> <chr> <chr> <chr> <chr> <chr> <chr> <chr>  <chr>  <chr> 
#> 1 1         2     3     4     5     6     7     8     9     10     11     12    
#> 2 1         2     3     4     5     6     7     8     9     10     11     12    
#> 3 This is … 2     3     4     5     6     7     8     9     10     11     12    
#> 4 1         2     3     4     5     6     7     8     9     10     11     12    
#> 5 1         2     3     4     5     6     7     8     9     10     11     12    
#> 6 This is a noth… 2     3     4     5     6     7     8     9      10     11    
#> 7 1         2     3     4     5     6     7     8     9     10     11     12    
#> # … with 17 more variables: col_13 <chr>, col_14 <chr>, col_15 <chr>,
#> #   col_16 <chr>, col_17 <chr>, col_18 <chr>, col_19 <chr>, col_20 <chr>,
#> #   col_21 <chr>, col_22 <chr>, col_23 <chr>, col_24 <chr>, col_25 <chr>,
#> #   col_26 <chr>, col_27 <chr>, col_28 <chr>, col_29 <chr>
```

<sup>Created on 2023-03-12 with [reprex v2.0.2](https://reprex.tidyverse.org)</sup>

The trailing semicolons are interpreted as another column that contains an empty string. To convert those to NA as well, add the line `mutate(across(everything(), ~na_if(.x, "")))` to the pipe.

Comment: I couldn't find the function `separate_wider_delim` @dufei

Comment: This function was recently added to the package tidyr which is part of the tidyverse. Update this package and try again!

Comment: Good job @dufei, it worked well. I need to add the original column names in the new file.

Comment: The cool thing about this function is that I don't need to know exactly how many columns my file has completely. Works well for looped iterations.

Answer (score 1):

I will recommend using the `readLines` function and later processing the line by line in accordance with your strategy.
You can use `stringi::stri_count("a;b;c", fixed = ";")` function to recognize number of ;.

e.g. when you want to skip the lines without 28 ;.

```r
# stringi dependency
df_lines <- readLines("PATH.txt")
df_lines_h <- df_lines[1]
df_lines_h_split <- strsplit(df_lines_h, ";")[[1]]
df_lines_body <- df_lines[-1]
res <- list()
for (line in df_lines_body) {
  n_semi <- stringi::stri_count(line, fixed = ";")
  if (n_semi == 28) {
    line_split <- strsplit(line, ";")[[1]]
    res <- append(res, list(line_split))
  }
}
final <- do.call(rbind, append(list(df_lines_h_split), res))
```

Comment: I am going to try @polkas